# Hook into button clicks on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Can I hook into all click events in Unity?

We would want to remember the UI action trail, to send to Crashlytics in case of a crash. We can individually go into the button click events, 100s of buttons in various scenes, and write an function in there, like MyDebug.LogAction(), but I was wondering IF it is possible to centrally hook into all clicks.

Sort of like how someone in C++ can hook into new operator (overload it), to e.g. do some debug time tracing of memory issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75809455/7111561) might be to implement your custom [`InputModule`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/InputModules.html) to be used by the `EventSystem`.

There you could overwrite the default click handling globally and "inject" additional stuff to happen without having to touch every button.

E.g. if you look into the [`InputSystemUIInputModule` source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/InputSystem/blob/develop/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem/InputSystem/Plugins/UI/InputSystemUIInputModule.cs) you will find

> ```
>     private void ProcessPointerButton(ref PointerModel.ButtonState button, PointerEventData eventData)
>     {
>         var currentOverGo = eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject;
>
>         if (currentOverGo != null && PointerShouldIgnoreTransform(currentOverGo.transform))
>             return;
>
>         // Button press.
>         if (button.wasPressedThisFrame)
>         {
>             button.pressTime = InputRuntime.s_Instance.unscaledGameTime;
>
>             eventData.delta = Vector2.zero;
>             eventData.dragging = false;
>             eventData.pressPosition = eventData.position;
>             eventData.pointerPressRaycast = eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast;
>             eventData.eligibleForClick = true;
>             eventData.useDragThreshold = true;
>
>             var selectHandler = ExecuteEvents.GetEventHandler<ISelectHandler>(currentOverGo);
>
>             // If we have clicked something new, deselect the old thing and leave 'selection handling' up
>             // to the press event (except if there's none and we're told to not deselect in that case).
>             if (selectHandler != eventSystem.currentSelectedGameObject && (selectHandler != null || m_DeselectOnBackgroundClick))
>                 eventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject(null, eventData);
>
>             // Invoke OnPointerDown, if present.
>             var newPressed = ExecuteEvents.ExecuteHierarchy(currentOverGo, eventData, ExecuteEvents.pointerDownHandler);
>
>             // If no GO responded to OnPointerDown, look for one that responds to OnPointerClick.
>             // NOTE: This only looks up the handler. We don't invoke OnPointerClick here.
>             if (newPressed == null)
>                 newPressed = ExecuteEvents.GetEventHandler<IPointerClickHandler>(currentOverGo);
>
>             // Reset click state if delay to last release was too long or if we didn't
>             // press on the same object as last time. The latter part we don't know until
>             // we've actually run the press handler.
>             button.clickedOnSameGameObject = newPressed == eventData.lastPress && button.pressTime - eventData.clickTime <= kClickSpeed;
>             if (eventData.clickCount > 0 && !button.clickedOnSameGameObject)
>             {
>                 eventData.clickCount = default;
>                 eventData.clickTime = default;
>             }
>
>             // Set pointerPress. This nukes lastPress. Meaning that after OnPointerDown, lastPress will
>             // become null.
>             eventData.pointerPress = newPressed;
>             eventData.rawPointerPress = currentOverGo;
>
>             // Save the drag handler for drag events during this mouse down.
>             eventData.pointerDrag = ExecuteEvents.GetEventHandler<IDragHandler>(currentOverGo);
>
>             if (eventData.pointerDrag != null)
>                 ExecuteEvents.Execute(eventData.pointerDrag, eventData, ExecuteEvents.initializePotentialDrag);
>         }
>
>         // Button release.
>         if (button.wasReleasedThisFrame)
>         {
>             // Check for click. Release must be on same GO that we pressed on and we must not
>             // have moved beyond our move tolerance (doing so will set eligibleForClick to false).
>             // NOTE: There's two difference to click handling here compared to StandaloneInputModule.
>             //       1) StandaloneInputModule counts clicks entirely on press meaning that clickCount is increased
>             //          before a click has actually happened.
>             //       2) StandaloneInputModule increases click counts even if something is eventually not deemed a
>             //          click and OnPointerClick is thus never invoked.
>             var pointerClickHandler = ExecuteEvents.GetEventHandler<IPointerClickHandler>(currentOverGo);
>             var isClick = eventData.pointerPress == pointerClickHandler && eventData.eligibleForClick;
>             if (isClick)
>             {
>                 // Count clicks.
>                 if (button.clickedOnSameGameObject)
>                 {
>                     // We re-clicked on the same UI element within 0.3 seconds so count
>                     // it as a repeat click.
>                     ++eventData.clickCount;
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     // First click on this object.
>                     eventData.clickCount = 1;
>                 }
>                 eventData.clickTime = InputRuntime.s_Instance.unscaledGameTime;
>             }
>
>             // Invoke OnPointerUp.
>             ExecuteEvents.Execute(eventData.pointerPress, eventData, ExecuteEvents.pointerUpHandler);
>
>             // Invoke OnPointerClick or OnDrop.
>             if (isClick)
>                 ExecuteEvents.Execute(eventData.pointerPress, eventData, ExecuteEvents.pointerClickHandler);
>             else if (eventData.dragging && eventData.pointerDrag != null)
>                 ExecuteEvents.ExecuteHierarchy(currentOverGo, eventData, ExecuteEvents.dropHandler);
>
>             eventData.eligibleForClick = false;
>             eventData.pointerPress = null;
>             eventData.rawPointerPress = null;
>
>             if (eventData.dragging && eventData.pointerDrag != null)
>                 ExecuteEvents.Execute(eventData.pointerDrag, eventData, ExecuteEvents.endDragHandler);
>
>             eventData.dragging = false;
>             eventData.pointerDrag = null;
>
>             button.ignoreNextClick = false;
>         }
>
>         button.CopyPressStateFrom(eventData);
>     }
> ```

You could basically create a copy of that module but extend it with whatever you need in there.

Answer (score 1):

Not by default.

As an option, you can create your own Button class, derived from the Unity button, and make your tracking there. For example, in overridden `OnPointerClick` method.

Then you can automatically replace all Button scripts on the prefabs you are using with your own Button class.